# How to properly bind a list to a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to bind a list to a datagrid using ItemSource:

xaml.cs

```
<UserControl x:Class="DDCUI.CommDiagnosisWPFCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="800" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="300" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="DGComm" CanUserResizeColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=dataGridRows}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No." Binding="{Binding Number}" Width="0.1*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" Width="0.1*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Protocol" Binding="{Binding Protocol}" Width="0.15*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source" Binding="{Binding Source}" Width="0.15*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Destination" Binding="{Binding Destination}" Width="0.15*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data}" Width="0.5*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <RichTextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="150" Name="RtbHexCode"/>
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="200" Name="TreeViewDecode"/>

    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

code:

```
public class CommDGDataSource
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

private List<object> dataGridRows = new List<object>();

private void DGAddRow(string name, FunctionType ft)
{
    CommDGDataSource ds = new CommDGDataSource();
    ds.Protocol = name;
    ds.Source = "";
    ds.Destination = "";
    ds.Number = rowCount.ToString();
    ds.Data = "";
    ds.Time = "";
    dataGridRows.Add(ds);
}
```

When DGAddRow is called, the DataGrid doesn't update its values.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Also, the XAML pre-generates empty rows even before they are filled with data. I want to be able to display only the rows that are filled with items (and add the new rows to the bottom of the last filled row). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ObservableCollection<> instead of List<> and make dataGridRows public.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the **first** thing that surprises me is that `dataGridRows` is private field. If I'm not mistaken, you can't bind to private field and it's better to make it public property.(correct me if I'm wrong).

The **second** thing bothering me is that one `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, not sure how grid works when `AutoGenerateColumns` is `True` and columns are explicitely specified. Try to set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

And the **third** one: as @Rover has already said, try to set type `datagridRows` to  `ObservableCollection<CommGDDataSource>`

Comment: If he declares his own columns `AutoGenerateColumns` attribute must be set to `False`.